# SyntaxError: Unexpected token at Object.parse (native)

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this haml code in a template,

```
.movie_container{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieGroup | orderBy:'release_date'"}
  %a{:href => "#", "ui-sref" => ".container-big({value: '{{movie}}'})"} More info
```

When a user clicks on the `a ui-sref` element I load a new state called `home.container-big`. I also pass my movie string data to the `home.container-big` state so I can use the data in there.

```
.state('home.container-big',{
  params: {
    value: null
  },
  url: '',
  views: {
    "container-big":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movie-info.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.movie = JSON.parse($stateParams.value);
        console.log ($scope.movie)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In this state I have a controller. In the controller I have a scope called movies. The data string from the previous state gets converted to JSON and placed in my `$scope.movies` so I can use it on the `_movie-info.html` template,

So far, so good.

```
.container-info{"ng-style" => "{'background-image':'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280{{movie.backdrop}})'}"}

  %ul.trailers
    %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in filteredTrailers = (trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id})"}
      %a{"ui-sref" => ".container-big-trailer({value: '{{ trailer.link }}' })"} {{ trailer.link }}

  .container-trailers
    %div{"ui-view" => "youtube_trailer"}
```

In this template I make a list of all the trailers in my db and filter them by movie_id. When a user clicks on the `a ui-sref=".container-big-trailer` I enter a new state called `.container-big-trailer` and pass the data from `trailer.link` as a value to that state.

And on this click I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token y
  at Object.parse (native)
```

It looks like the token has something to do with the value of `trailer.link` because the token is the first token of the value of `trailer.link`, except for trailers that start with the letter N or F (and maybe a few more).

*** EDIT ***

If I remove the `{value: '{{ trailer.link }}' }` from the `ui-sref` link and then click like so,

```
  %ul.trailers
    %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in filteredTrailers = (trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id})"}
      %a{"ui-sref" => ".container-big-trailer()"} {{ trailer.link }}
```

And then console.log what the value is of my `.container-big-trailer` state is,

```
.state('home.container-big.container-big-trailer',{
  params: {
    value: null
  },
  url: '',
  views: {
    "youtube_trailer":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_container-trailer.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.value = $stateParams.value;
        console.log ('big-trailer' + $scope.value)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It outputs the string data of the value given with state `home.container-big`.

Comment: Can you convert your haml code to regular HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else runs into the same problem. The bug was that I had defined my `$stateParams` with the same `value`. I thought that `value` was a way to get the data, but it's just a name. I changed one `value` to `movie_info` and replaced it as well in the template and now it's working.